# Writing a comparable for an Arrays.Sort of Points

Tags: java, arrays, comparable, points

I have this code :

```
import java.awt.Point;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Haupt {

    // creates an array of anz Point objects
    public static Point[] generatePointArray(int anz) {
        Point[] pa = new Point[anz];
        for(int i = 0; i < anz; i++) {
            int px = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
            int py = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
            pa[i] = new Point(px,py);
        }
        return pa;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Point[] pointArray = generatePointArray(15);

        Arrays.sort(pointArray);


        for(int i = 0 ;  i < pointArray.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Point: "+pointArray[i] +
            " has distance "+pointArray[i].distance(0,0)+
            " from origin");
        }
    }
}
```

And as you may see I want to sort a point Array, therefore I wrote (nearly) a comparable :

```
import java.awt.Point;

public class MyPoint extends Point implements Comparable {
    public int compareTo(Object o)
    {
        Point p = (Point) o;


        if () {
            return -1;
        }
        if () {
            return 1;
            }
        return 0;
    }

}
```

What do I need to write inside the `if()` clause?

***Edit: From the comments***

> The condition would be that I look after the value of the distance
>   between the point(0,0) and Point (x,y) (If this is even possible

Comment: Well, how do you want to sort the array? What points go first?

Comment: How do you think two points should be logically compared?

Comment: Do not use *raw* generics. Use `Comparable<MyPoint>`.

Comment: Maybe I could look at the x or y values.

Comment: @Altin what to look into the x,y values, what order would be expected here?

Comment: @nullpointer I don't get the question really to be honest. I mean that I could look after the x values  and then the lowest goes to the highest.

Answer (score 4):

Implementing the `compareTo` method depends entirely on how you want to sort these points. One plausible way to do so is by their X and Y coordinates:

```
public class MyPoint extends Point implements Comparable<MyPoint> {
    public int compareTo(MyPoint o) {
        int retVal = Double.compare(getX(), o.getX());
        if (retVal != 0) {
            return retVal;
        }
        return Double.compare(getY(), o.getY());
    }
}
```

Alternatively, instead of creating your own class that implements the `Comparable` interface, you could use a custom [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html). With Java 8's enhancements, it would even be quite elegant:

```
Arrays.sort(
    pointArray, 
    Comparator.comparing(Point::getX).thenComparing(Point::getY)
);
```

EDIT:
The comments added a suggestion to sort the points by their distance from the origin (0, 0). This is also easily doable with both mechanisms. The distance of a point from the origin is defined as `sqrt(x*x + y*y)`. Since `sqrt` is a monotonic transformation that does not affect the ordering, it can be omitted for a slight performance gain.

As `Comparaable`:

```
public class MyPoint extends Point implements Comparable<MyPoint> {
    public int compareTo(MyPoint o) {
        return Long.compare(getCompareKey(), o.getCompareKey());
    }

    private long getCompareKey() {
        return (getX() * getX()) + (getY() * getY());
    }
}
```

With a custom `Comparator`:

```
Arrays.sort(
    pointArray, 
    Comparator.comparing(p -> (p.getX() * p.getX()) + (p.getY() * p.getY())
);
```

Comment: *sort the points by their distance to the origin* this wouldn't work in that case

Comment: @nullpointer of course it won't, because this isn't the sorting criteria I implemented :-). But this requirement doesn't appear anywhere in OP.

Comment: Ya, unfortunately in comments to clear the requirements.

Comment: @nullpointer Just saw the discussion in the comments (should probably be edited into the question itself) - will edit my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the distance from origin using a private method in your class as:

```
private int distanceFromOrigin(Point point) {
    return (int) Math.sqrt(Math.pow(point.getX(), 2) + Math.pow(point.getY(), 2));
}
```

Then the `compareTo` method could be modified to include comparison between the distance of two `Point`s as :

```
public int compareTo(Object o) {
    Point p = (Point) o;
    if (distanceFromOrigin(p) > distanceFromOrigin(this)) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (distanceFromOrigin(p) < distanceFromOrigin(this)) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is not the right comparison. This comparison say that current point always preced the second point, or they are at the same distance. Check the direction of your boolean tests.

Comment: To just compare the distance, you don't need to take the square root (it is a monotonic function). Just compare the square of the distance.

Comment: @Henry Agreed, I could read the same in Mureinik'as answer as well. But since I derived a util method there, hence didn't update the answer further. Anyway the monotonic function can be reused is the intention here :)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you would like to compare two points.
The implementations differ if you:

- say that p1 precede p2 if it is closer to the origin (0, 0)
- say that p1 precede p2 if the x coordinates of p1 comes before p2
- say that p1 precede p2 if the sum of x and y coordinates of p1 comes before those of p2

There are potentially thousands of possible comparisons!

---

Here an example of code tha compare points by their distance to the origin (and in case the distance is equal comparing their position on x and y axis):

**Note** It is not necessary to calculate the real distance to check which point is closer to the origin. If you calculate the power of two of the distance you will get the same result using less cpu (so it is possible to remove the calculation of the square root). You are sure to obtain the same result because a distance is always a positive number. Additionaly using the expression `x * x` is faster than using the expression `Math.pow(x, 2)`. This optimization can be useful in this context because often geometric operations involve milions of points.

```
 public class MyPoint extends Point implements Comparable {
    public int compareTo(Object o) {
        Point p = (Point) o;

        // Note that if sqr(x^2 + y^2) < sqr(p.x^2 + p.y*2) 
        // Also x^2 + y^2 < p.x*2 + p.y*2 but you save
        // computing cicles
        // THis is possible because we are comparing distances,
        // it is not necessary to calculate the right distance if
        // you need only to know the comparison between them
        if (x*x + y*y < p.x*p.x + p.y*p.y) {
           return -1;
        } else if (x*x + y*y > p.x*p.x + p.y*p.y) {
           return 1;
        } 

        // In case of same distance to origin compare x and subsequent y positions.

        if (x > p.x) {
            return -1;
        } else if (x < p.x) {
            return 1;
        } else if (y < p.y) {
            return 1;
        } else if (y > p.y) {
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;
     }
}
```

---

Here a possible implementation that compare two points by x coordinates and if they are equals comparing y coordinates.

```
 public class MyPoint extends Point implements Comparable {
    public int compareTo(Object o) {
        Point p = (Point) o;

        if (x > p.x) {
            return -1;
        } else if (x < p.x) {
            return 1;
        } else if (y < p.y) {
            return 1;
        } else if (y > p.y) {
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;
     }
}
```

Comment: You might want to update the answer according to the requirements as updated in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare `x` and `y` coordinates of both the points using lambda, e.g.:

```
Arrays.sort(points, (Point p1, Point p2) -> p1.getPx() == p2.getPx() ? 
        p1.getPy() - p2.getPy() : p1.getPx() - p2.getPx());
```

**Update**

Based on question edits, you can calculate the distance with `Sqrt(x2 + y2)` formula and use it while comparing two points, e.g.:

```
Arrays.sort(points, (Point p1, Point p2) -> (int) Math.sqrt(Math.pow(p1.getPx(), 2) + 
        Math.pow(p1.getPy(), 2) - Math.sqrt(Math.pow(p2.getPx(), 2) + Math.pow(p2.getPy(), 2))));
```

Answer (score 0):

First calculate the distance from origin using a  method in your class as:

> Keep the precision value. Don't cast into INT, as it might be needed to compare the close points. For many points distance as integer values might be same.

```
private double distance(Point p) {
    return (double) Math.sqrt(Math.pow(p.getX(), 2) + Math.pow(p.getY(), 2));
}
```

Then the compareTo method could be as follow.

> Use compareTo method designed for wrapper classes.

```
public int compareTo(Object o) {

    return new Double(distance(this)).compareTo(distance(Point(p)));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would vote against your approach with creating a subclass
`MyPoint extends Point implements Comparable<Point>`.

Instead I suggest to use the `Array.sort(T[], Comparator<T>)` method
with a taylor-made `Comparator<Point>`.

When using Java 8 you can write it very concisely like this:

```
Point[] pointArray = generatePointArray(15);
Arrays.sort(pointArray, Comparator.comparingDouble(p -> p.distance(0, 0)));
```

For Java 7 (and older) you need to use the more verbose syntax
with an anonymous class:

```
Point[] pointArray = generatePointArray(15);
Arrays.sort(pointArray, new Comparator<Point>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Point p1, Point p2) {
        return Double.compare(p1.distance(0, 0), p2.distance(0, 0));
    }
});
```